# Create Set to get Last month of Each Year

Tags: ssas, mdx

I would like to create a set that returned the last Date for each year. For example all previous years would return December, but the current year would only return the current month.

```
WITH 
  SET testset AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
      Generate
      (
        {
            OpeningPeriod([Date].[Calendar].[Month])
          : 
            ClosingPeriod([Date].[Calendar].Month)
        }
       ,{[Date].[calendar].CurrentMember}
      )
     ,[Measures].[Sale Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    (
      [Measures].[Sale Amount]
     ,[Date].[Year].[Year]
    ) ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [testset] ON 1
FROM [Cube]
```

Here is an example of a script that returns the values for each month. I've tried using tail and lastchild, but that only returns the most recent. I would like it to return for every Year.

Comment: are future months included in your cube? Can I assume there is data for all months apart from future months?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of just the last month - ignoring whether there is data for it or not the following:

```
WITH 
  SET [AllYears] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS 
  SET [LastMths] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [AllYears] AS S
     ,Tail
      (
        Descendants
        (
          S.CurrentMember
         ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month]
        )
       ,1
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,[LastMths] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Returns this:

[image]

If I want to adapt the above so that it is the last month per year that has data for a specific measure then wrap `NonEmpty` around the set created by `Descendants`:

```
WITH 
  SET [AllYears] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS 
  SET [LastMths] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [AllYears] AS S
     ,Tail
      (
        NonEmpty //<<new
        (
          Descendants
          (
            S.CurrentMember
           ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month]
          )
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] //<<new
        )
       ,1
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,[LastMths] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It now gives us this:

[image]

We can then add in the tuple you have on rows  (I have used the attribute hierarchy this time for years as `[Date].[Calendar]` is already in use)

```
WITH 
  SET [AllYears] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS 
  SET [LastMths] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [AllYears] AS S
     ,Tail
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          Descendants
          (
            S.CurrentMember
           ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month]
          )
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        )
       ,1
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    (
      [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
     ,[Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year]
    ) ON 0
 ,[LastMths] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Now we get this:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

@Whytheq has already given a very good solution. Treat this as an alternative. This might be a `tad` faster as it doesn't use the `GENERATE` function (not sure though!).

Have a calculated/cube measure which basically tells whether a month is the last month of the year. Then select those months out of the set of months.

```
with member measures.islastchild as
iif
    (
       [Date].[Calendar].currentmember is 
       [Date].[Calendar].currentmember.parent.parent.parent.lastchild.lastchild.lastchild,
       1,
       null
    )
```

The member `measures.islastchild` returns 1 if the month is the last month of the year. Else it would return `null`.

```
set lastmonths as
filter(
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].members, 
        measures.islastchild = 1
      )
```

The set `lastmonths` is then the set you need.

**edit**

To further improve the performance, you can `NonEmpty` function instead of the iterative `FILTER` function.

```
set lastmonths as
NonEmpty(
         [Date].[Calendar].[Month].members, 
         measures.islastchild
        )

select lastmonths on 1,
{} on 0
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2: To get the last non month with sales**

```
with member measures.islastnonemptychild as
iif
    (
       [Date].[Calendar].currentmember is 
       TAIL(NonEmpty([Date].[Calendar].currentmember.parent.parent.parent.lastchild.lastchild.children, [Measures].[Sale Amount])).ITEM(0),
       1,
       null
    )

set nonemptylastmonths as
NonEmpty(
         [Date].[Calendar].[Month].members, 
         measures.islastnonemptychild 
        )
```

Comment: (upped) for the inclusion of `.parent.parent.parent.lastchild.lastchild.lastchild` !!

Comment: How would you alter this so it only showed the latest month with Data?

Comment: @user3266792 - ideally this should be a different question. You would have to modify the member and the set a little to achieve that. As I am not near my system, have added a rough edit. Hope it helps.